# How to convert a column with missing values to string?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, string, nan

I need to export a dataframe from pandas to Microsoft SQL Server using SQL Alchemy. Many columns are strings, with missing values and with some very long integers, e.g. 999999999999999999999999999999999 . These numbers are some kind of foreign key, so the value itself doesn't mean anything, so I can convert those to strings.

This causes the following error in SQL Alchemy when trying to export to SQL:

```
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

I tried converting to string with `astype(str)`, but then I run into the problem that missing values, identified as nans, are converted into the string 'nan' - so SQL does not see them as nulls but as the string 'nan'.

**The only solution I have found is to first convert to str then replace 'nan' with `numpy.nan`. Is there a better way?** This is cumbersome, relatively slow, and as unpythonic as it can get: first I convert everything to string, the conversion turns nulls into strings, so I convert those into NaN, which can be a float only, and I end up with a mixed-type column.

Or do I simply have to suck it up and accept that pandas is dreadful at dealing with missing values?

I have an example below:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, time

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, select
import sqlalchemy as sqlalchemy

start=time.time()
ServerName = "DESKTOP-MRX\SQLEXPRESS"
Database = 'MYDATABASE'
params = '?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + ServerName + '/'+ Database + params, encoding ='latin1' )
conn=engine.connect()

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['mixed']=np.arange(0,9)
df.iloc[0,0]='test'
df['numb']=3.0
df['text']='my string'
df.iloc[0,2]=np.nan
df.iloc[1,2]=999999999999999999999999999999999

df['text']=df['text'].astype(str).replace('nan',np.nan)

df.to_sql('test_df_mixed_types', engine, schema='dbo', if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `np.where` would certainly be a bit faster compared to replace i.e

```
df['text'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['text']),df['text'],df['text'].astype(str))
```

Timings :

```
%%timeit
df['text'].astype(str).replace('nan',np.nan)
1000 loops, best of 3: 536 µs per loop

%%timeit
np.where(pd.isnull(df['text']),df['text'],df['text'].astype(str))
1000 loops, best of 3: 274 µs per loop

x = pd.concat([df['text']]*10000)
%%timeit
np.where(pd.isnull(x),x,x.astype(str))
10 loops, best of 3: 28.8 ms per loop

%%timeit
x.astype(str).replace('nan',np.nan)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: The solution with np.where also correctly handles the edge case where the Series already contains the str "nan". The solution with replace incorrectly replaces that with np.nan where it should just pass on the str "nan".

Answer (score 2):

To keep NaN as NaN and only convert non-NaN rows to `str`, use boolean indexing.

```py
msk = df['text'].notna()
df.loc[msk, 'text'] = df.loc[msk, 'text'].astype(str)
```

or use `mask()` method to select values depending on a condition (whether the value is non-NaN), much like `np.where()`.

```py
df['text'] = df['text'].mask(lambda x: x.notna(), df['text'].astype(str))
```

If however, you want to make NaNs into empty strings (perhaps to operate on the strings later), then use `fillna()`.

```py
df['text'] = df['text'].fillna('').astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas = Nan
Nan -> null

```
db_update = db_update.replace({np.nan: None})
```